# .htaccess configuration with static page and wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Apparently I'm drawing a blank - must be a simple, stupid issue....

Scenario:

Website hosted by a provider w/ Apache WS - no root access. Existing **static** website is located in folder public_html (index.html). The existing .htaccess contains a single line: `DirectoryIndex index.html`. The server's start directory is public_html.

A working WordPress Installation is located in `public_html/folder_wp` (i. e. when switching the server's start directory from `public_html` to `public_html/folder_wp` WordPress is executed upon calling the website from any browser).

The static website contains a button with link to `folder_wp/index.php` - the purpose is to redirect to the WP site from the static website.

Both - static and WP site - share the same URL.

Any hint highly welcome. -mgw

Problem: When clicking the link that should launch to the WP site a 403 is displayed.

I fiddled around with several settings in .htaccess to no avail and only ended up with either 404 or 500 besides the 403.

Last tried with `public_html/.htaccess` and added directory index.php - funny enough I can now reach the WP site but when clicking anywhere I end up with 404 (wp_admin not found et al.)... guess I need some rewrite rule or else...? New .htaccess:

```
#KONSOLE AREA START - PLEASE DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BETWEEN THESE LINES
DirectoryIndex index.html
#KONSOLE AREA END - PLEASE ADD MANUAL CHANGES BELOW
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Permission issues? What are the permissions of index.php? Owner, group and others. If it's a 403 issued by Apache itself remember that the file should be readable by www-data (on a standard installation on a Debian derivative) or by the user running the apache service in general.

Comment: Also, check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Does WP redirect to `folder_wp/`? Might interfere with the `DirectoryIndex index.html` line in the webhome. Try to add `DirectoryIndex index.php` in the `.htaccess` in `public_html/folder_wp/`.

Comment: @kos no permission issue. All folders 755 and WP files according to rules.

Comment: @stoney actually there are two .htaccess one in `public_html` and the WP-built in `folder_wp`. Adding index.php or folder_wp/index.php into public_html/.htaccess led to same issue.